# Java NullPointException on Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets, jdbc

I am developing registration system with jsp and servlet, and when I tun locally I don't get NullPointerException. But when I deploy it into remote server I get this NullPointerException.

Is there any errors in my code.

```
package com.app.base;

//imported necessary packages. removes for readability.

public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = null;
    // Connection connection = null;
    // Statement statement;
    // ResultSet rs;

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    out = resp.getWriter();

    String fname = req.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = req.getParameter("lname");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    String city = req.getParameter("city");
    String country = req.getParameter("country");

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        // Load the JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // Create a connection to the database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306,/main",
                "root", "root");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp?error=SQLError");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp?error=Class Not Found");
    }

    PreparedStatement statement;
    try {
        statement = connection
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO main.users(first_name, last_name, email, password, "
                        + "city, country, registered_time)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?, NOW())");
        statement.setString(1, fname);
        statement.setString(2, lname);
        statement.setString(3, email);
        statement.setString(4, password);
        statement.setString(5, city);
        statement.setString(6, country);

        int rs = statement.executeUpdate();

        if (rs == 1) {
            resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp?registered=true");
            // String destination = "index.jsp?registered=true";
            // RequestDispatcher rd =
            // getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
            // rd.forward(req, resp);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp?registered=false");
    }

}

}
```

The stacktrace:

```
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Register] in context with path [] threw exception
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.base.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1688)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Are you sure your database runs on localhost:3306 when you deploy it on a remote server?

Comment: Look at the first line of your stack trace:

`at com.app.base.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:79)`.

What is there at line 79?

Comment: Can you print what is at line 79 of RegisterServlet.java

Comment: Line 79 is statement = connection
     .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO main.users(first_name, last_name, email, password, "
       + "city, country, registered_time)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?, NOW())");

Comment: well, I changed it to localhost so I am not posting my mysql url, username and password here.

Comment: Add System.out.println(connection !=null); before line 79 and see if it prints true or false.

Comment: The only explanation for a NPE on line 79 is that `connection` is null.

Answer (score 2):

In all likely hood the driver class is not found, meaning that the call to `Class.forName()` throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. You send a redirect (btw, without logging the exception which is not a good idea, you can already see now that you have a hard time finding the error) but you don't return from your call. Leaving the connection to be `null` and causing the NPE later in your code when you try to call `prepareStatement`).

Add a `return ;` after you send a redirect to stop your call.

Of course you should find one way or another to have that driver available on your Tomcat.

Comment: do you think the error in Connection connection = null;? But if it is null why I get an error when I execute SQL?

Comment: no, you have to initialize connection.But the problem is that when you call Class.forName() it actually throws a ClassNotFoundException so you go right into the catch block, send the redirect and then continue to process the call. When you get to the prepareStatement, connection is still null.

Comment: ok, what's the solution for that? Is it all right if I remove connection initialization and use Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306,/main",
     "root", "root"); inside try block?

Comment: Yes and no. It will work if you bring all your code regarding the statement preparation in the try/catch block as well. But after all, your main issue is actually that your driver class cannot be found by the classloader. You should probably post another question to ask how to get your driver class on your webapp classpath

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly put extra , in your string

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306,/main",
            "root", "root");
```

notice the `,/main`

instead it should be

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/main",
            "root", "root");
```

Sorry If this is not the right answer I am not an expert like all the people above